# Leading zero in any column of a CSV file is lost when opened in Excel 2007

Tags: java, csv

I'm looking for a way to preserve leading zeros in integers when exporting to a CSV file in Java. The following is an example of generating leading zeros into a CSV.

```
public class TestLargeDataset {

    int one_million = 1000000;

    public void writeMillionRowsToCSVFile(String fqname) throws Exception {
        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(fqname)));

        byte[] newLine = "\n".getBytes();

        for(int x = 0; x < one_million; x++) {
            bos.write(("0" + x + ",").getBytes());
            bos.write(("0" + (x+1) + ",").getBytes());
            bos.write(("0" + (x+2) + ",").getBytes());
            bos.write(("0" + (x+3)).getBytes());
            bos.write(newLine);
        }
        bos.close();
    }

    /*
     * Main.
     */
    public static void main(String a[]) throws Exception {
        TestLargeDataset tlr = new TestLargeDataset();      

        long startTime2 = System.nanoTime();
        tlr.writeMillionRowsToCSVFile("C:\\output_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".csv");
        long diff2 = (System.nanoTime() - startTime2)/1000000000;
        tlr.log("Executed file write operation in " + diff2 + " seconds (~" + (diff2/60) + " minutes)");

        tlr.getStatement().close();
        tlr.getConnection().close();

        tlr.log("Execution complete.");
    }

}
```

When I open the output file in Excel 2007, I lose the leading zeros. Is there a way to preserve these zeros and open the same in Excel WITHOUT converting then into Strings? The reason for not converting them into Strings is cos' I would need integer arithmetic applied to these values in the excel.

Thoughts?

Comment: A number with leading zeros **is** a string.

Comment: As @ceeyayoz said, a number has no leading zeros, so there's nothing to preserve. If it has leading zeros, it's a string, and integer arithmetic doesn't apply. You need to decide if they're integers (and therefore don't have leading zeros and can be used as integers) or strings, which can have leading anything.

Comment: You may be able to accomplish this with custom formats for integers in Excel: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/81518/using-a-custom-number-format-to-display-leading-zeros

Answer (score 6):

Found this solution on another forum and it worked for me.

Append a double quote and tab, problem will rectify. Tab prevent leading zeors from truncating and double quote separation of a cell when numbers has comma(,) with in it.

String yourString = "002015";

Solution:

"\"\t"+yourString + "\"";